# Proving a function is convex

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, convex-analysis

From the Defintion of convex:

[image]

**Theorem to be proven:**

> If $f$ is differentiable and $f'$ is increasing, then $f$ is convex. *Use Proof by Contradiction.*

Consider, $I = (a, b)$ with $a < x < b$.

If $f(x)$ is convex then,

$$\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x-a} < \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b-a}, \space \forall x$$

Suppose,

$$\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x-a} > \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b-a} \space \mathrm{for \space some} \space x$$

From MVT< $\exists x_1$:

$$\exists x_1 \in (a, b) \implies f'(x_1) = \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b-a}$$

We have the inequality (from the assumptions) ,

$$f'(x) > f'(x_1)$$

If $x_1 > x$ then contradiction for $f'$ is increasing.

If $x_1 < x$ **<---- I cant come up with a contradiction?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I want to note that your definition of convexity corresponds to strict convexity. Thus, I'll have to assume that $f'$ is strictly increasing.

Let's have a look at the convexity condition first and reformulate it a little. So, for $a<x<b$ the convexity condition gives
$$
\begin{align}
& & \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} &< \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}
\\ \Leftrightarrow & & (f(x)-f(a))(b-a) &< (f(b)-f(a))(x-a)
\\ \Leftrightarrow & & (f(x)-f(a))(b-a) + (f(x)-f(a))(a-x) &< ((f(b)-f(a))(x-a) + (f(x)-f(a))(a-x)
\\ \Leftrightarrow & & (f(x)-f(a))(b-x) &< ((f(b)-f(a))(x-a) + (f(a)-f(x))(x-a)
\\ \Leftrightarrow & & (f(x)-f(a))(b-x) &< ((f(b)-f(x))(x-a)
\\ \Leftrightarrow & & \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} &< \frac{f(b)-f(x)}{b-x}.
\end{align}
$$

Now assume that $f$ is *not* convex. Then there exist $a<x<b$ such that
$$
\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} \geq \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}
$$
or, as we just computed, equivalently
$$
\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} \geq \frac{f(b)-f(x)}{b-x}.
$$
By the mean value theorem we get $\xi_1 \in (a,x)$ and $\xi_2 \in (x,b)$ with
$$
\begin{align}
f'(\xi_1) = \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} && \text{and} && f'(\xi_2) = \frac{f(b)-f(x)}{b-x}.
\end{align}
$$
If we combine this with the above inequality we have $\xi_1 < \xi_2$ with
$$
f'(\xi_1) = \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} \geq \frac{f(b)-f(x)}{b-x} = f'(\xi_2).
$$
But $f'(\xi_1) \geq f'(\xi_2)$ for $\xi_1 < \xi_2$ is a contradiction to $f'$ strictly increasing. Hence, the contradiction yields that $f$ must be convex.